# Elements are not changing colour

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have tried to write some basic CSS to change the style properties of a set of elements, however only some of them change to the background colour I want, whilst the rest stay white. for example my textarea, select and bootstraps panel heading will not change colour.

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Panel title
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="testchart">
            CHART GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is what I have attempted so far in my CSS

```
input[type="text"], textarea, option, #device-panel, .modal-body, .panel-body{
        background-color : #262626;
        color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-heading {
    background-color : #1E1F1F;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

my textarea's background colour and text colour also does not change and so along with my select control.  However with the select control, the options do change to the background colour I want and text colour.

Comment: Can you please crate a fiddle or can you add complete css for the calss?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, I can't understand what you need.

Comment: You've missed `select` from your styling options, but your textarea should style fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x9Ly4htr/1

Comment: sorry, missed the fact you were using bootstrap,  You will need to make sure your selectors for changing the colours are more specific than the bootstrap selectors so that you can overwrite them or to the same level of specificity but included after the initial styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Panel heading is not changing color because it is being overwritten by the default Bootstrap styling. Use `!important` keyword to forcefully overwrite the css like so:

```
.panel-heading{
    background-color : #1E1F1F !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

[Have a look at this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pna0fzb/)

Comment: I used this in the other css style as well and worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```css
input[type="text"], select, textarea, option, #device-panel, .modal-body, .panel-body{
  background-color : #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-heading {
  background-color : #1E1F1F;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<textarea>test</textarea>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```